# bracket with doubled delimiters

Tags: spacing, brackets, delimiters

I want to typeset Hilbert-Schmidt-Products as the Liouville-Equivalent of the Hilbert Space Braket, with doubled delimiters, like this: `\Lbraket{\rho|\rho}` results in `<<rho|rho>>`.

I was trying to adapt the definition of `\Braket` from the [Braket](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/braket/) package to do this, ending up with the following code:

```
{\catcode`\|=\active                                                             
  \xdef\Lbraket{\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname Lbraket \endcsname}         
  \expandafter\gdef\csname Lbraket \endcsname#1{\begingroup                      
     \ifx\SavedDoubleVert\relax                                                  
       \let\SavedDoubleVert\|\let\|\BraDoubleVert                                
     \fi                                                                         
     \mathcode`\|32768\let|\BraVert                                              
     \left\langle\kern-0.2em\left\langle{#1}\right\rangle\kern-0.2em\right\rangle\endgroup}
}
\def\BraVert{\@ifnextchar|{\|\@gobble}% turn || into \|                          
     {\egroup\,\mid@vertical\,\bgroup}}                                          
\def\BraDoubleVert{\egroup\,\mid@dblvertical\,\bgroup}                           
\let\SavedDoubleVert\relax
\begingroup                                                                      
 \edef\@tempa{\meaning\middle}                                                   
 \edef\@tempb{\string\middle}                                                    
\expandafter \endgroup \ifx\@tempa\@tempb                                        
 \def\mid@vertical{\middle|}                                                     
 \def\mid@dblvertical{\middle\SavedDoubleVert}                                   
\else                                                                            
 \def\mid@vertical{\mskip1mu\vrule\mskip1mu}                                     
 \def\mid@dblvertical{\mskip1mu\vrule\mskip2.5mu\vrule\mskip1mu}                 
\fi
```

This works, but for very large formulas the double delimiters are not sufficiently tight, and the negative kerning should be larger.

On the other hand, I've found some code that allows to define double delimiters
and doesn't seem to suffer from the same problem. The following is from a
[newsgroup posting](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2010-05/msg00245.html), it defines `\lleft` and `\rright` so that e.g.
`\lleft\langle` results in `<<`.

```
\catcode`@=11                                                                    
\def\lleft#1#2\rright{\begingroup%                                               
   \def\ts@r{\nulldelimiterspace=0pt \mathsurround=0pt}%                         
   \let\@hat=#1%                                                                 
   \def\sht@im{#2}%                                                              
   \def\@t{{\mathchoice{\def\@fen{\displaystyle}\k@fel}%                         
          {\def\@fen{\textstyle}\k@fel}%                                         
          {\def\@fen{\scriptstyle}\k@fel}%                                       
          {\def\@fen{\scriptscriptstyle}\k@fel}}}%                               
   \def\g@rin{\ts@r\left\@hat\vphantom{\sht@im}\right.}%                         
   \def\k@fel{\setbox0=\hbox{$\@fen\g@rin$}\hbox{%                               
      $\@fen \kern.3875\wd0 \copy0 \kern-.3875\wd0%                              
      \llap{\copy0}\kern.3875\wd0$}}%                                            
      \def\pt@h{\mathopen\@t}\pt@h\sht@im%                                       
      \rright}%                                                                  
\def\rright#1{\let\@hat=#1%                                                      
   \def\st@m{\mathclose\@t}%                                                     
   \st@m\endgroup}                                                               
\catcode`@=12
```

My question is if there's a way to combine to two code snippets to get a correctly resizing Braket with doubled delimiters. Simply doing the following does not work:

```
{\catcode`\|=\active                                                             
  \xdef\LBraket{\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname LBraket \endcsname}         
  \expandafter\gdef\csname LBraket \endcsname#1{\begingroup                      
     \ifx\SavedDoubleVert\relax                                                  
       \let\SavedDoubleVert\|\let\|\BraDoubleVert                                
     \fi                                                                         
     \mathcode`\|32768\let|\BraVert                                              
     \lleft\langle{#1}\rright\rangle\endgroup}
}
```

This results in an error message:

```
! Extra \middle.
\mid@vertical ->\middle |
```

My knowledge of lowlevel TeX is not anywhere near sufficient to understand how
the implementation of `\lleft` and `\rright` works, but maybe someone sees
whether the two snippets can be combined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A modification of the very clever `\lleft` macro can do

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\makeatletter
\def\LBlleft#1#2|#3\LBrright{\begingroup
   \def\ts@r{\nulldelimiterspace=0pt \mathsurround=0pt}%
   \let\@hat=#1%
   \def\sht@im{\ts@r\left.#2\nonscript\;\middle|\nonscript\;#3\right.}%
   \def\@t{{\mathchoice{\def\@fen{\displaystyle}\k@fel}%
          {\def\@fen{\textstyle}\k@fel}%
          {\def\@fen{\scriptstyle}\k@fel}%
          {\def\@fen{\scriptscriptstyle}\k@fel}}}%
   \def\g@rin{\ts@r\left\@hat\vphantom{\sht@im}\right.}%
   \def\k@fel{\setbox0=\hbox{$\@fen\g@rin$}\hbox{%
      $\@fen \kern.3875\wd0 \copy0 \kern-.3875\wd0
      \llap{\copy0}\kern.3875\wd0$}}%
      \def\pt@h{\mathopen\@t}\pt@h\sht@im
      \LBrright}%
\def\LBrright#1{\let\@hat=#1%
   \def\st@m{\mathclose\@t}%
   \st@m\endgroup}
\DeclareRobustCommand\LBraket[1]{\LBlleft<#1\LBrright>}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\LBraket{\frac{a}{b}|b}$
$\textstyle\LBraket{\frac{a}{b}|b}$
$\scriptstyle\LBraket{\frac{a}{b}|b}$
$\scriptscriptstyle\LBraket{\frac{a}{b}|b}$
\end{document}
```

## ADDED (Support for multiple bars)

```
\makeatletter

\def\LB@add@@{\aftergroup\LB@add@}
\def\LB@add@{\aftergroup\LB@add}
\def\LB@add{\advance\@tempcnta\@ne}
\def\LB@barsl{\ifcase\@tempcnta\or
  \kern-\nulldelimiterspace\left.\or
  \kern-2\nulldelimiterspace\left.\left.\fi}
\def\LB@barsr{\ifcase\@tempcnta\or
  \right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\or
  \right.\right.\kern-2\nulldelimiterspace\fi}

\def\LBlleft#1#2\LBrright{\begingroup
  % count the number of bars
  \mathcode`|="8000
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`| \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\aftergroup\LB@add@@}
  \@tempcnta=\z@\setbox\z@=\hbox{$\left<#2\right>$}
  % now \@tempcnta has the number of bars and we redefine |
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`| \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\nonscript\;\middle|\nonscript\;}
  \def\ts@r{\nulldelimiterspace=0pt \mathsurround=0pt}%
  \let\@hat=#1%
  \def\sht@im{\LB@barsl#2\LB@barsr}%
  \def\@t{{\mathchoice{\def\@fen{\displaystyle}\k@fel}%
          {\def\@fen{\textstyle}\k@fel}%
          {\def\@fen{\scriptstyle}\k@fel}%
          {\def\@fen{\scriptscriptstyle}\k@fel}}}%
   \def\g@rin{\ts@r\left\@hat\vphantom{\sht@im}\right.}%
   \def\k@fel{\setbox0=\hbox{$\@fen\g@rin$}\hbox{%
      $\@fen \kern.3875\wd0 \copy0 \kern-.3875\wd0
      \llap{\copy0}\kern.3875\wd0$}}%
      \def\pt@h{\mathopen\@t}\pt@h\sht@im
      \LBrright}%
\def\LBrright#1{\let\@hat=#1%
   \def\st@m{\mathclose\@t}%
   \st@m\endgroup}
\DeclareRobustCommand\LBraket[1]{\LBlleft<#1\LBrright>}
\makeatother
```

It supports at most two bars, but if needed one can extend the macros `\LB@barsl` and `\LB@barsr`.

Comment: Works almost, except for the second vertical in e.g. `\LBraket{\rho| \hat{\hat{A}} | \rho}`, the way `\Braket` does. Would there be a way to incorporate that as well?

Comment: Well, that indeed does two bars, but unlike the first version, it doesn't seem to scale the negative spacing between the two delimiters. Actually, if someone can pick it apart, I'd love to be able to understand how the original `\lleft` macro works... what's the trick there?

Comment: @MichaelGoerz See edited answer; I'm still studying the `\lleft` and `\rright` magic. :)

Comment: @egreg: Is it possible to modify the code in such a way that the following works: `\LBlleft{\{[}#1{]\}}\LBrright`. I mean to set two different delimiters.